# Recursion Result stack

Tags: php, function, recursion, stack

What is the cleanest way to pass the result of this recursive function back out?

```
function recursion_trigger($input, $count = 0){

        if(!empty($input)){
                array_pop($input);
                $count++;
                if(!empty($input)){
                recursion_trigger($input,$count);
                }
        }

echo $count;
return $count;


}
```

At the moment it is returning the top most call which is of course one.

/////// as an additional question this is the full function can you use tail recursion here? The output is an array that I am constructing as I pass through the values.

```
<?php    
//Page best viewed from page source 

 //Takes an array of objects that have ID and Parent and organizes the tree into an array representing a set of objectID's by depth 

 // poor spelling ahead =P

function level_keys($array,$depth=-1,$level=0,$output=null){

// initialize the functions parameters run once at start and not in subsequent self calls

if($level == 0 && $depth != 0){
    $output[][]=0;
    $level++;
        foreach($array as $key=>$node){
            if($node->parent==0){
                $output[$level][] = $node->id;
                unset($array[$key]);
            }
        }
            unset($key); unset($node);
$level++;
$depth--;

}

// set recursion loop and run main part of function

if (  !empty($array) && $depth != 0){

    echo 'depth:'.$depth."\n";

    foreach($output[$level-1] as $parent){  
        foreach($array as $key=> $child){
            if( $parent == $child->parent){
            $output[$level][] = $child->id;
            unset($array[$key]);
            }
        }
    }
        unset($id); unset($parent); unset($key); unset($child);
$depth--;
$level++;
        if(!empty($array) && $depth !=0 ){
            // make sure to pass the output back out to the top most level
            $output = level_keys($array,$depth,$level,$output,$depth_at);
        }
}

return $output;

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you really need is not to count the number of elements in an array.

When you do recursive functions like this one, it is good for performance if they are tail-recursive (in fact, I'm not sure php has this optimisation, I hope so). Here you have $count that can serve as accumulator but don't use it.

```
function recursion_trigger ($input, $count = 0)
{
  if (!empty($input)) {
    array_pop($input);
    return recursion_trigger($input, $count + 1);
  }
  return $count;
}
```

This way it works and is tail recursive :-).

Comment: Haha no it was a good way to abstract out the non-important part of the problem. Also I found this link for any one else who happens here. http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?TailRecursion

Comment: I understand the benefit of tail recursion how could I apply it to the function that I have edited in the above question.

Answer (score 1):

You should update your `$count` variable with the return value of `recursion_trigger`

```
if(!empty($input)){
    $count = recursion_trigger($input,$count);
}
```

EDIT:

Hopefully the following will help you visualise how it's working:

```
recursion_trigger ( array("This", "Is", "A", "Sample"), 0)
  recursion_trigger ( array("This", "Is", "A"), 1)
    recursion_trigger ( array("This", "Is"), 2)
      recursion_trigger ( array("This"), 3)
        recursion_trigger ( array(), 4)
```

Comment: Thank you that was exactly it.I understand why it works but I am still having trouble visualizing how it works.

Answer (score 1):

The way you were thinking probably was along the lines that `$count` was persistent, whereas it isn't because of call by value. This version, using references, also works.

```
function recursion_trigger($input, &$count = 0){

        if(!empty($input)){
                array_pop($input);
                $count++;
                if(!empty($input)){
                recursion_trigger($input,$count);
                }
        }

echo $count;
return $count;


}
```

Comment: I had considered that but this will eventually be a function in Java. I was just trying to visualize how everything was going to work and PHP is a very quick language to work with. Thank you.